# How to remove network addresses from a list if they are a subnet of another network

Tags: python-3.x, subnet

After creating a list of ipaddress/CIDR from a csv file, converting the ipaddresses to network addresses and then eliminating duplicates by creating a set from the list (python 3.7), I iterate and eliminate all subnets that are subnets_of() another subnet, keeping the summarized or supernet address. I use the ipaddress module to do this work. The problem is, if the subnet is compared to itself, it still counts as a subnet. for example,

```
a = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')
b = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')
b.subnet_of(a)
True
```

So I even if there is a 192.168.0.0/23 in my list, the /24 is still added because all addresses are compared to all addresses. Is there a better to handle this type of situation?

I've tried removing the the subnet from my working list so it won't be iterated over again, no luck.

No error messages. I just get a subnet included that fits within a larger subnet in my list. This leaves an entry that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just removing everything after the `/`?

Comment: That would negate the ipaddress modules ability to determine the prefix length for the network, subnet membership could not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

The `*Network` objects compare for equality so you can modify the condition like so:

```py
In [21]: import ipaddress

In [22]: a = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')

In [23]: b = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')

In [24]: a.subnet_of(b) and a != b
Out[24]: False
```

but that will still leave you with duplicates on your list.

The [`netaddr` package](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has a [`cidr_merge`](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.cidr_merge) function that does what I think you want:

```py
In [33]: from netaddr import cidr_merge

In [34]: cidr_merge(['192.168.5.0/24', '192.168.0.0/24', '192.168.0.0/28', '192.168.0.0/24'])
Out[34]: [IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/24'), IPNetwork('192.168.5.0/24')]
```